# the attributes of files demonstrated by ls -l

Tags: bash

I tried

```
greedy@algorithms:~$ ls -l /
total 2097292
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 11月 28 15:55 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 11月 28 16:34 boot
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root       4096 5月   8  2018 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root       4540 12月  2 00:40 dev
drwxr-xr-x 135 root root      12288 12月  1 07:32 etc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root       4096 11月 27 20:53 home
```

what does the second column and the 7th column mean? especially the large number 135?

Comment: See [What is the number between file permission and owner in ls -l command output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43046/what-is-the-number-between-file-permission-and-owner-in-ls-l-command-output)

Comment: Steeldriver has already provided a link, but I'd just `stat /bin` to view stats for that directory, and you'll see pretty easily the values & why they are what they are  for /bin in the `ls -l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second column shows the number of (hard) links to that file system object.

A regular file has one hard link by default, which would be represented by just its normal file path. More hard links could be added to it with the `ln` command. Those extra hard links would just be regular files in the file system again, but point to the exact same file on disk as your original file descriptor.

Directories normally have two hard links by default, as they're referenced once by themselves (`.`) and once as entry from their parent directory. They also have one hard link as parent of each of their subdirectories. So the 135 in your case would mean that your `/etc` folder should have 133 subdirectories, plus the two default links.

What you label the 7th column is actually the day part of the modification timestamp.